# Why does the loop fail when using RecursiveIteratorIterator?

Tags: php

when

```
$jsonIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(new RecursiveArrayIterator(json_decode($myJSON, TRUE)),RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST);
```

I put it in a while loop, it stops the loop.

I can't find the reason

Comment: please, show us your loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved.

Because of the use of var_dump The loop would stop.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).